# Automatically load data on scroll of paper-scroll-header

Tags: javascript, angularjs, polymer, polymer-1.0

I am working on a project using Polymer and Angular JS
The code now is not organized as this is just a tutorial
However im trying to load a huge amount of data on the screen

In order to do this I have used ng-repeat on the li tag with filter , orderby and limitto

I wish to increase the limitto variable everytime i reach a point on scroll

On googling iron-scroll-threshold fullfills my requirement. However when i try to implement it, it doesnot respond as expected.

also the size variable is placed in $scope.size and how do i use this in polymer?

for the timebeing to demo what exactly i wish to accomplish I have added a button which on click does the needful.

You can find my code in https://github.com/chrisgiffy/chrisgiffy.github.io

An the demo in http://chrisgiffy.github.io

Can someone please help me out?

P.S. Im a noob in Angular and Polymer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way i could solve this was by using ngInfiniteScroll widget

```
<div ng-app="flash" ng-controller="cardController" class="flex" fixed id="headerPannel" infinite-scroll="scroll()" infinite-scroll-distance="3">
....
</div>

$scope.scroll = function(){
    if($window.scrollTop()>=720){
      $scope.size = +$scope.size + 50;
    }
    else if($window.scrollTop()<=200) {
      $scope.size = 50;
    }
  };
```